# rewrite the sas code to improve its efficiency

Tags: sas

I have `(b.sslag1 - b.sslag100)`. Is there any built-in function in SAS can accomplish the same goal while improve its efficiency?

```
(case when a.ss = . and b.sslag1 ^=. then b.sslag1
      when a.ss = . and b.sslag1 =. and b.sslag2 ^=. then b.sslag2
      when a.ss = . and b.sslag1 =. and b.sslag2 =. and b.sslag3 ^=. then b.sslag3
      when a.ss = . and b.sslag1 =. and b.sslag2 =. and b.sslag3 =. and b.sslag4 ^=. then b.sslag4
      ....
      else a.ss end) as ss
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the coalesce function.

```
   coalesce(a.ss, b.sslag1, b.sslag2, b.sslag3, b.sslag4) as ss
```

In a data step you can use the short hand notation. Short hand notation does not work in PROC SQL.

```
coalesce(a.ss, of b.sslag1-b.sslag100);
```

Comment: Do you have to use SQL? In a data step you can use shorthand notation to refer to all of the variables at once. Or is only 1 of the 100 filled in or multiples? Otherwise can create variable list via a macro variable.